# Display Json tree Boootstrap

Tags: angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angular js , I have to display JSON data (can be nested to any level)in tree structure whchi should expand and collapse on button click ,I have tried various npm plugins but not a satisfied with any of those , 
So can anybody suggest me some good solution for this 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with plugins, then **angular-ui-tree** is the best one.

Else you can come up with your own logic of iterating the nodes with check in record array, if its there come up with caret and give the control to hide and show the rows of the respective parent.